# How do I mock a JSF FacesContext with a ViewMap for Unit Tests outside an actual web application?

Tags: jsf, junit, mocking, facescontext

**EDIT:** Cleaned up the question for readability. Please ignore comments up to October 31st.

In our application stack we work with many smaller jar modules that get combined into a final web application. One module defines JSF features, like implementing [this](http://www.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/) ViewScope.

Now appart from integration testing we want to be able to unit test every part and thus need a way to mock a complete Faces Context (to be accessed via a wrapper) to test classes that use it.

The important part here is **complete** meaning it has to have an initialized `ViewMap` as this is where our `ViewScope` puts its objects.

---

I've tried different approaches:

**1) shale-test**: I've come the furthest with this but unfortunately the project is retired.

So far I've wrapped the FacesContext in a Provider which allows me to replace it with a Mocked FacesContext for testing. I've also modified the shale implementation of AbstractViewControllerTestCase to include an application context.

However when calling `MockedFacesContext.getViewRoot().getViewMap()` as this will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The reasons seems to be that the MockApplication does not instantiate Application.defaultApplication (it's null) which is required for this method call. This seems to be a shale-test limitation.

---

**2) [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html) or mockito** These seem to me not to not really mock anything at all as most members will just remain null. Don't know if JMock or mockito can actually call the propper initialization methods.

---

**3) Custom Faces Mocker:** To me this seems the only remaining option but we don't really have the time to analyse how Faces is initialized and recreate the behaviour for mocking purposes. Maybe someone has dont this before and can share major waypoints and gotchas?

---

Or is there any alternative way to mock a FacesContext outside a web application?

Comment: I have no idea about the Jmock part, but the exception is just trying to tell you that the `javax.el.ELContext` class is missing in the current runtime classpath. An obvious fix would be to include it in the runtime classpath. Configure your project's buildpath to include the libs of the target runtime (the servletcontainer/appserver).

Comment: As per your edit, the EL API is a **dependency** of the JSF API. It's been used to resolve those `#{}` things. The EL API is usually already provided by the target runtime (Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish, etc).

Comment: Ah, nice. Including the EL dependency helped. The mocked context is still quite unusable but it's one step at a time.. maybe someone still has more ideas about how to use jmock with facesContext or how to unit test classes that use FacesContext.getcurrentinstance() like the ViewScope implementation mentioned above. (It seems I wont't get around a FacesContext Wrapper/Provider..? but what's the best way to mock a FacesContext?)

Comment: Just because Shale is retired doesn't meant you can't obtain it.  The last version is in the Apache Attic and can be downloaded.  I use it and it works perfectly fine for just mocking FacesContext

Comment: yeah I tried shale again after including the EL dependencies and got somekind of faces context. however it is not fully functional: calling `getViewRoot().getViewMap()` will throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`

This can be traced back to MockApplication not instantiating the private field `Application.defaultApplication` (when calling `ApplicationFactory.getApplication()`).
I don't know if that ever worked or if it's just the lack of further development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/)+Mockito:

From your link:

```
private Map<String,Object> getViewMap() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();
}
```

In the test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class });
public class TheTest {
    /*
     * fake viewMap.
     */
    private Map<String,Object> viewMap = Maps.newHashMap() // guava

    /**
     * mock for FaceContext
     */
    @Mock
    private FacesContext faceContext;

    /**
     * mock for UIViewRoot
     */
    @Mock
    private UIViewRoot uiViewRoot;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Mockito.doReturn(this.uiViewRoot).when(this.faceContext).getViewRoot();
        Mockito.doReturn(this.viewMap).when(this.uiViewRoot).getViewMap();

        PowerMock.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
        PowerMock.doReturn(this.faceContext).when(FacesContext.class, "getCurrentInstance");
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        /*
         * do your thing and when  
         * FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap(); 
         * is called, this.viewMap is returned.
         */
    }
}
```

Some reading:

- http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll try that as soon as we get back to the frontend in our app. That might take a while though so please be patient about the bounty ;)

Comment: Point is helping not getting a bounty ;o